# How to change color of specific word in richtextbox in datagird?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

i want to change color of specific word in richTextBox in DataGrid.
But I don't know how to access richTextBox in DataGrid.
I can't access Rchtxt that is name of richTextBox.
Is there anyone who know that? or another way to change color.

this is my code:

```
<DataGrid Name="Data"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="contents" x:Name="headerb">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RichTextBox x:Name="Rchtxt" TextChanged="rtb_TextChanged">
                            <FlowDocument Name="rtbFlowDoc" PageWidth="{Binding ElementName=rtb, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=BODY}" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>



private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;
        string find = "apple";

        String text = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

        if (text.Contains(find))
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, find))
            {
                TextPointer myTextPointer1 = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index);
                TextPointer myTextPointer2 = myTextPointer1.GetPositionAtOffset(find.Length);

                rtb.Selection.Select(myTextPointer1, myTextPointer2);
                rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new media.SolidColorBrush(media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)));
            };
        }
  }
```

Comment: isnt the sender in that case would be the richTextBox itself?

Comment: i think i solved it! but i have another problem... can you see my new code?

Comment: i got wrong charoffset of myTextPointer1, 2.. why is it happend?